# Incorrect string value for Croatina characters

Tags: php, mysql

I have html form and php script for inserting some values in mysql table.
Table fields are set to utf8_unicode_ci. 
While inserting Croatian letters (žšđčć) i get error Incorrect string value: '\x9A\xF0\xE8... etc for column Name at row 1. I've found some help searching google and one of solution was to change field to ut8mb4 but still have same problem.

I'm running mySQL 5.6.14, php 5.5.11 on XAMPP 1.8.3

This is html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />



<form name="Prijava" method="post" action="insert.php">
<fieldset>
<legend>Personal information:</legend>
Ime:<br>
<input type="text" name="_ime" maxlength="50">
<br>
Prezime:<br>
<input type="text" name="_prezime" maxlength="50">
<br>
Spol:<br>
<input type="radio" name="_spol" value="M" checked>M
<br>
<input type="radio" name="_spol" value="Z">Ž
<br>
Godište:<br>
<input type="text" name="_godiste" maxlength="4"<br>
<br>E-mail adresa:<br>
<input type="text" name="_emailadresa" maxlength="50">
<br>
Grad/mjesto:<br>
<input type="text" name="_gradmjesto" maxlength="50">
<br>
Tip:<br>
<input type="radio" name="_tip" value="Klub" checked>Klub
<br>
<input type="radio" name="_tip" value="Udruzenje">Udruženje
<br>
<input type="radio" name="_tip" value="Solo">Solo
<br>
<br>
<p><input onchange="this.setCustomValidity(validity.valueMissing ? 'Molimo Vas potvrdite da prihvaćate uvijete!' : '');" id="field_terms" type="checkbox" required name="terms"> Prihvaćam <u>uvijete</u></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</fieldset>

<a href="select.php">Pregled popisa prijavljenih natjecatelja</a>
</form>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

and this is php:

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");

if (!isset($_POST['_ime']) ||
!isset($_POST['_prezime']) ||
!isset($_POST['_spol']) ||
!isset($_POST['_godiste']) ||
!isset($_POST['_emailadresa']) ||
!isset($_POST['_gradmjesto']) ||
!isset($_POST['_tip']))
{
    died ("Nisu popunjena svi podaci!");
} else
{
$ime = $_POST['_ime'];
$prezime = $_POST['_prezime'];
$spol = $_POST['_spol'];
$godiste = $_POST['_godiste'];
$email = $_POST['_emailadresa'];
$grad = $_POST['_gradmjesto'];
$tip = $_POST['_tip'];


$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO prijave (IDUnos, Ime, Prezime, Spol, Godiste, Email, Grad, Tip) VALUES (null, '$ime', '$prezime', '$spol', '$godiste', '$email', '$grad', '$tip');";

mysql_query($sql_insert) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close($con);

}


// slanje poruke

$to      = $email;
$subject = 'Prijava na utrku';
$message = 'Ovdje ide poruka';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) )
{
header('Location: finish.html');
}


?>
```

What else to do to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure it's on utf8_unicode_ci? Here its working just fine. My mySQL is an earlier version tho.

Comment: Yes. I've just checked. Don't know what to do... Table fields accepts special characters but inserting and displaying data doesn't show correct.

Answer (score 0):

When I have to deal with special characters I always look at a couple things:

1. Database, table and field character sets are all set to utf8_unicode_ci.
2. Use header to modify the HTTP header. `header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");`
3. Specify the default character set to be used when sending data from and to the database server: `mysqli_set_charset($connect, 'utf8');` helpfull [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_set_charset.asp).

So I think your problem is in the connection between script and database.